# Magento 2 Add Product Admin page not loading

Tags: php, apache, magento2

I am fairly new to Magento. I installed magento on ubuntu and have been running in Developer mode. I tried to add products from Admin using Catalog -> Products -> Add product. the page never loads it shows No Data From server or The connection was reset.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

please add memory limit in your index.php file on the root of magento

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```